# Rewrite file url using htaccess

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

This is the path to a directory which stores images of all the users:

> localhost/demo/images/imagedb/user/**xyz.jpg**

Instead of showing all the directory names and actual path, I want to display the image in the directory like this:

> localhost/demo/userdp/**xyz.jpg**

I tried the following code but it did not work and gave me error

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule   ^demo/images/imagedb/user/(.+)$   demo/userdp/$1   [L]
```

Could you provide me with a solution?

Comment: It should be the opposite - left part is what you request, right - is what it should be rewritten to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL to be entered goes first, like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule   ^demo/userdp/(.+)$   demo/images/imagedb/user/$1   [L]
```